# Debugging in Visual Studio 2013 with a reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, reverse-proxy, iis-express

I have a situation where I will be working with another app via a reverse proxy. I need the host app (asp.net and MVC) to be able to talk via JavaScript to the proxied app and I'd like to be able to test and debug in visual studio. Does anyone know of a way to get an ARR/URLRewrite2 reverse proxy to work in iis express with visual studio 2013?

Thanks in advance!